# how to restrict only admin to add user?

Tags: angularjs, express

Iam new to express.js. I got strucked with problem of adding user only by admin. and also user should not bee add if admin  logged out. Here is my code please can any one help me. Iam using **`express.js, mongodb`**.

it is server side code

**`route.js`**

```
app.route('/auth/signin').post(users.signin);
app.route('/auth/adduser').post(users.in,users.adduser);
```

**`express.js`**

This is my **`signin`** code

```
exports.signin = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err || !user) {
            res.status(400).send(info);
        } else {
            // Remove sensitive data before login
            user.password = undefined;
            user.salt = undefined;

            req.login(user, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                } else  {

                     req.session.value = user;
                    res.jsonp(user);


                }

            });
        }
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

This is **`adduser`** code

```
exports.in=function(req,res,next){
var user=req.session.value;
console.log('user details get from signin page'+JSON.stringify(user));
if(user.username===config.admin.username){
next();   //it goes to add user page
}
else{
res.send('your not a Admin');
}

};


exports.adduser = function(req, res) {
    delete req.body.roles;

    var user = new User(req.body);
    var message = null;
// Add missing user fields
    user.provider = 'local';
    user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
    user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
         res.jsonp(user);
            console.log('user added');
        }
    });
};
```

But, while exceuting the code it gets **error** that **`req.session.value is undefined`**
i.e..,the data is not getting from signin page.
 The main aim of posting this code is admin only has to add the user when he login .otherwise should  send a message like  you are not an admin or please login....

Answer (score 0):

Actually passport sets the user on `req` object with `logIn()` method so you dont need this line

```
 req.session.value = user; // remove this
```

and you can just get user on

```
console.log(req.user);
```

**To verify this**

Add this middleware in server.js or you app.js

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.user);
    next();
    });
```

here after the login occurs and authenticate plus `logIn()` methods are called , refreshing the page will console.log your user

**Adding custom object/varaibles to session**

to add user object or any thing else on session of passport you can do this as follow

```
req.session.passport.hi = "hello";
```

**to verify this** after adding this to session on subsequent page refresh see console when using following middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.session.passport.hi);
        next();
        });
```